# How do I get a <span> string output by knowing its innerhtml in php?

Tags: php, html, regex, wordpress, preg-match

I am trying get the string structure produced between a `<span>` element when it includes the text "Bonkers".

For example:

```
  <span>    Bonkers </span>
```

or

```
 <span>    Bonkers           </span>
```

or

```
<span>              Bonkers                          </span>
```

The thing is I don't know span structure, but I know "Bonkers" will be in there.

I want to return the entire text string structure (including the < span > open and close tags so that later I can replace it.
eg:

```
$spanwithbonkers  = '<span>      Bonkers                      </span>';
```

So far this is what I have, but it does not work:

```
 <?php

 $homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');

  preg_match('/^<span>^Bonkers^</span>/', $homepage, $matches);

  $spanwithbonkers = $matches[0]);


?>
```

Not sure if preg_match is even supposed to be used.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/787016

Comment: Like I said, i'm not sure if preg_match is even supposed to be used. I need a solution!

Comment: If there are no `<` `>` in between, you can use [`<span>[^<]*?\bBonkers\b[^<]*<\/span>`](https://regex101.com/r/QQ0O4X/1/). It uses [negated](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `<` in between opening and closing span tags. If you want to write a crawler for arbitrary html, better [look for a html parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php).

Comment: Your code returns a var_dump string of:                        string(33) " Bonkers"    I assume that there are 33 empty spaces, but I don't know how to get it to return the < span > tags including the empty spaces

Comment: Make it an answer so I can give you credit. Although I can't see the empty space, when I used the $spanwithbonkers as the string, it picked it up!

Answer (score 1):

A better way than using regex to parse HTML is using the [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) classes. You can load the HTML into a document, then use XPath to find specific elements and then process those elements. In your case, we find spans including the word `Bonkers` by comparing the `text` value of each span node e.g.

```
$html = '<body><div><div><span id="b">    Bonkers  </span></div></div>
         <div><span> no bonk</span>
              <span> This is bonkers!</span>
         </div></body>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$spans = $xpath->query("//span[contains(text(), 'Bonkers')]");
foreach ($spans as $span) {
    echo $span->C14N();
}
```

Output:

```
<span id="b"> Bonkers </span>
```

If you want to do a case-insensitive comparison, it's a little more complex:

```
$spans = $xpath->query('//span');
foreach ($spans as $span) {
    if (stripos($span->textContent, 'Bonkers') !== false) {
        echo $span->C14N() . "\n";
    }
}
```

Output

```
<span id="b"> Bonkers </span> 
<span> This is bonkers!</span>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/JtNQF)